# Trouble understanding JavaScript API example with VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net, json, asp.net-ajax, jsonp

I am a new vb.net developer and I'm trying to integrate with an API service that allows me to store credit card data without being PCI compliant. The issue i have is that the example is provided only for JavaScript, and I an having trouble figuring out how to create the same simple procedure in vb.NET.  I was hoping someone might be able to assist me with this sample.

The idea is to direct POST this data from my form to the API, and then process the success or failed response data.

```
        //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input:button').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'https://certify.i4go.com/index.cfm',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: {
                        fuseaction: 'account.jsonpPostCardEntry',
                        i4Go_AccountID: '123123',
                        i4Go_SiteID: '456456',
                        i4Go_CardNumber: $('#i4Go_CardNumber').val(),
                        i4Go_ExpirationMonth: $('#i4Go_ExpirationMonth').val(),
                        i4Go_ExpirationYear: $('#i4Go_ExpirationYear').val()
                    },
                    cache: false
                });
            });                 
        });
        function parseResponse(data) {
            if (data.i4go_responsecode != null) {
                if (data.i4go_responsecode == 1) {
                    $('#response').html('i4Go_UniqueId: ' + data.i4go_uniqueid);
                } else {
                    $('#response').html('i4Go_ResponseCode: ' + data.i4go_responsecode);
                }
            } else {
                $('#response').html('i4Go_ResponseCode is null');
            }
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>Card number:</td><td><input type="text" id="i4Go_CardNumber" value="4111111111111111"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Exp month:</td><td><input type="text" id="i4Go_ExpirationMonth" value="12"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Exp year:</td><td><input type="text" id="i4Go_ExpirationYear" value="2020"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="Get Token"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <div id="response"></div>
```

I appreciate any and all help.

Cheers,

AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on .NET 4.5, look into the new WebAPI calls which make this pretty easy. Once you create a class representing the data, the serialization is all done for you, and your code will look something like:

```
Dim jsonObject As ' TODO: Create a class that represents the data, and instantiate the object with the data
Dim client As New HttpClient()
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://certify.i4go.com/")
Dim result As HttpResponseMessage = client.PostAsJsonAsync("index.cfm", jsonObject).Result
```

Analyze the returned object to get whatever they're passing back to you, and decide how to proceed from there.

There are plenty of overloads to choose from, all doing basically the same thing.

**EDIT**:
For .NET 4.0, you can use `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient` - it's a little more work, but still not too bad - you just have to handle the serialization manually. There are again probably a lot of ways of doing this, but here's one:

```
Dim message As String
Dim s As New SomeData() ' SomeData still represents the data you're passing
message = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(s)
Dim webClient As New WebClient()
Dim response() As Byte = webClient.UploadData(url, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message))
Dim responseString as String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response)
```

Now that you have the response as a string, you can figure out what to  do with it - it's probably a JSON object or something like that, which you'll need to read or deserialize.

Comment: Joe, thank you for the help.  I am currently on .NET 4.0, how might i implement this without the new HttpClient ?

Comment: Edited answer with 4.0 example.